# Playframework 2.1.x Database Error

Tags: database, scala, import, playframework

I try to add a database to my play framework app but I have several problems. I used the template (from `Typesafe Activator`) called `"hello-play-2_3-scala"`. I always get an error if i try to insert `'import play.api.db._'`. I looked at [this](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaDatabase) instruction for the play database, but the main problem is I haven't any `Build.scala` file in my project folder. Also I cannot create once, just Java Files (I use Intellj Idea). I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Greetings Chryb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `jdbc` dependency inside `build.sbt` file. It should look like this:

```
name := """hello-play-2_3-scala"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  PlayKeys.jdbc,
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3-M1",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1",
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.11-1"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).addPlugins(PlayScala)
```